# Remove one level in the middle of a folder tree

Tags: windows-7, tree, directory

I'm using Windows 7 and would like to remove a middle level of a folder tree while maintaining the files inside those folders. For example:

```
C:\folder1\folder2\files
```

I want to remove "folder2" and keep "files".

Comment: Are you looking for a batch file? C# code? A Powershell script? What?

Comment: Well, I'm not good at programming so whatever I can get to work with my little expertise...

Answer (score 0):

Open a command prompt, and type:

```
MOVE c:\folder1\folder2\*.* c:\folder1
RMDIR c:\folder1\folder2
```

Comment: This will work, thank you, but I actually didn't answer your question completely. It would be for a batch of over 2700 folder trees.